# django Queryset became List after a for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm using django for my website ,the problem is hard to tell,please see code below.(python 2.7.10)

```
In [1]: user = User.objects.filter(pk__gt = 1)
In [2]: type(user)
Out[2]: django.db.models.query.QuerySet

In [3]: user1=user[0:user.count()]
In [4]: type(user1)
Out[4]: django.db.models.query.QuerySet
```

obviously ,user and user1 is QuerySet, now the problem come:

```
In [1]: user = User.objects.filter(pk__gt = 1)
In [2]: type(user)
Out[2]: django.db.models.query.QuerySet

In [3]: for i in user:pass
In [4]: user1=user[0:user.count()]
In [5]: type(user1)
Out[5]: list
```

The user is also QuerySet,but the user1 became list.

The only diffirent betweet these two code is a for loop

```
 for i in user:pass
```

I am confused about what happend in that for loop ?

Comment: I don't have this behaviour here, and I fail to see how a for loop would rebind the name of the iterable to another object.

Comment: The for loop triggwrs the evaluation of the queryset, probably. QS are lazy

Comment: I input these code in  manage.py shell, is this matter?

Comment: @Pynchia : the evaluation of the Queryset wont turn it into a list, nor rebind the name in the local scope.

Comment: @KongDeqiang I of course tried the same code pattern in a django shell (with my current project's models of course but they're nothing special, plain django models). Please restart a fresh django shell and try again, I suspect you had a typo or something else going on. Or it might be IPython going out of it's way and doing some stupid thing behind your back so please retry the same code without IPython.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It's werid, I guess i need to try another computer.

Comment: @Pynchia I've already seen it (and commented).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By running the `for` loop you do what Django calls *evaluating* the `QuerySet`. Before that, it is said to be *lazy*, which means that adding filters and other `QuerySet` methods do not actually hit the database.

An interesting snippet from [QuerySets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) (also see the example there):

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve
>   any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long,
>   and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is
>   evaluated.

There are a few statements and methods that evaluate your `QuerySet`, which are documented in [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) and include iteration and slicing an already evaluated `QuerySet`.

What this means is that once you ***evaluate*** a queryset, e.g. through iteration which you did with the `for` loop, Django will actually query the database. Once that is done this paragraph from the docs sums up the behavior you get after slicing the `QuerySet` with `user1=user[0:user.count()]` on `In [4]` in your second shell snippet.

> *Slicing.* As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced,
>   using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet
>   usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute
>   the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax,
>   and will return a list. **Slicing a QuerySet that has been evaluated
>   also returns a list.**